# I can't print char from string

Tags: .net, string, f#, char

I tried this:

```
open System
let main() =
    let mutable str1 = "qwerty"
    printfn "%c" str1[0]
main()
```

got this:

> error FS0597: Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized

I found this site: *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/strings*
and here it's working I don't know why. I found other sites, where everyone said about parentheses

```
open System
let main() =
    let mutable str1 = "qwerty"
    printfn "%c" (str1[0])
main()
```

and got this:

> error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied

Comment: The syntax you are using is legal, but quite new. So new that many haven't got this version of F# yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print a single character from a string you actually need to put a dot in between the object and the squared brackets.

```
printfn "%c" str1.[0]
```

[MSFT docs: Access elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/arrays#access-elements)

Here writes Microsoft:

> You can access array elements by using a dot operator (.) and brackets ([ and ]).

However, their example actually also does not include the `dot`. Nevertheless, in order to access array elements, you need to use the dot operator.